# Mirrored (flipped horizontally) after rendering image or movie

Tags: rendering, texturing, texture-baking

Everything looks great when orbiting 3D, the text on my texture boxes looks great using cycles.  But when I bake, or render a image or movie,... the image/text gets flipped horizontally.  I cannot find any help on this anywhere.  Here's hoping you'll help.
Here is a movie on vimeo showing my mirrored results... 
https://vimeo.com/62238175

Comment: Post the .blend file.

Comment: Is UV mapping properly set and material assigned to face, as well as an image assigned in UV editor?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a UV problem.
Try to select the UV face that is flipped and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to mirror, then press <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> to select the mirror direction.